# WPF XAML Designer crash in VS2012

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2012

I working on a very big solution with more than 80 projects.
My XAML designer crash each time a change been made on the Window.
Only if kill the process 'XDesProc.exe' and reload it again it start showing the designer again until the next change.

I'm using VS2012 UP2.

Please help me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check Microsoft support for help https://support.microsoft.com/oas/?gprid=16677&st=1&wfxredirect=1&sd=gn